# Importing external classes with out an IDE

Tags: java, jar, import

I'm just wondering how to import classes located in a .jar file with out using an IDE. The jar file is in the same directory as the java file.
So for example the jar file is called "someclasses.jar" and my file is called program.java

I've done research and I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure if I'm doing the class path correctly either. Is this close to how it should be done:

```
import someclasses.*;
```

and when compiling and running:

```
javac -cp '.:someclasses.jar' program.java

java -cp '.:someclasses.jar' program
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the *exact* error you are receiving. As-is if your class was not part of a package, there is nothing wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the class from this website:
https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/
its a metadata reader for image files.
i've just never used external libraries before and following other threads I just seem to get lost...

Comment: That ... doesn't answer what I asked. The problem is most likely with *your* class file and where you're running `javac` from, not their jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way.

```
javac -cp .:someclasses.jar program.java

java -cp .:someclasses.jar program
```

Regrading import statement, *it should be fully qualified name of the class* used, **NOT** name of the jar.* You have to execute these commands from top of the directory. Example like

```
javac -cp .:someclasses.jar com.test.program.java
```

Comment: Single quotes are ignored. That isn't the actual problem. If I had to make a wild guess without the actual error message the OP is receiving, their `program` class is in a package and they're not running `javac`/`java` from the top of the directory tree.

Comment: Ok. Regarding the import statement then, if the jar file has numerous classes, do i just import them as their name like this:

    import classinjarfile;
the library is from this site:
https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/
so i'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Please read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) to learn how to use packages